How to orientate the transform of a segment from a starting and ending point in bevy
I am trying to represent the segment of a cube, however i fail to create a way to orientate segments depending on their starting position and ending position.
What I've come up so far is to get the center and have the segment look at its starting points but it's not working as intended. Here's a working example that should work with bevy 1.14.2 :
use bevy::{
    input::mouse::{MouseMotion, MouseWheel},
    prelude::*,
};

mod cube;

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_systems(Startup, setup)
        .add_systems(Update, (update, camera_movement_action))
        .run();
}

#[derive(Component)]
pub struct GameCamera;

#[derive(Component)]
pub struct Object;

fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands<'_, '_>,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<StandardMaterial>>,
) {
    commands.spawn(PbrBundle {
        mesh: meshes.add(Cylinder::new(0.1, 8.0)),
        material: materials.add(StandardMaterial::default()),
        transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3 {
            x: 0.,
            y: 0.,
            z: 0.,
        })
        .with_rotation(Quat::from_euler(EulerRot::XYZ, 0., 1., 0.)),
        ..default()
    });

    commands.spawn(PointLightBundle {
        point_light: PointLight {
            shadows_enabled: true,
            intensity: 10_000_000.,
            range: 100.0,
            shadow_depth_bias: 0.2,
            ..default()
        },
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(8.0, 16.0, 8.0),
        ..default()
    });

    commands.spawn((
        Camera3dBundle {
            transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 7., 14.0)
                .looking_at(Vec3::new(0., 1., 0.), Vec3::Y),
            ..default()
        },
        GameCamera,
    ));
}

pub fn camera_movement_action(
    mut camera_transform_query: Query<&mut Transform, With<GameCamera>>,
    mouse_input: Res<ButtonInput<MouseButton>>,
    mut mouse_motion: EventReader<MouseMotion>,
    mut mouse_scroll: EventReader<MouseWheel>,
    _time: Res<Time>,
) {
    if let Ok(mut camera_transform) = camera_transform_query.get_single_mut() {
        if mouse_input.pressed(MouseButton::Right) {
            for motion in mouse_motion.read() {
                camera_transform
                    .rotate_around(Vec3::ZERO, Quat::from_rotation_z(motion.delta.y * -0.01));
                camera_transform
                    .rotate_around(Vec3::ZERO, Quat::from_rotation_y(motion.delta.x * -0.01));
                camera_transform.rotation =
                    camera_transform.looking_at(Vec3::ZERO, Vec3::Y).rotation;
            }
        }

        for scroll in mouse_scroll.read() {
            let forward = camera_transform.forward();
            camera_transform.translation += forward * scroll.y;
        }
    }
}

fn update(
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<StandardMaterial>>,

    object_query: Query<Entity, With<Object>>,
) {
    for entity in object_query.iter() {
        commands.entity(entity).despawn_recursive();
    }

    let points = vec![
        Vec3::new(1., 1., 1.),
        Vec3::new(1., -1., 1.),
        Vec3::new(1., 1., -1.),
        Vec3::new(1., -1., -1.),
        Vec3::new(-1., 1., 1.),
        Vec3::new(-1., -1., 1.),
        Vec3::new(-1., 1., -1.),
        Vec3::new(-1., -1., -1.),
    ];

    for point in points.iter() {
        commands.spawn((
            PbrBundle {
                mesh: meshes.add(Cuboid::new(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)),
                material: materials.add(StandardMaterial::default()),
                transform: Transform::from_translation(*point).with_rotation(Quat::from_euler(
                    EulerRot::XYZ,
                    0.,
                    5.,
                    0.,
                )),
                ..default()
            },
            Object,
        ));
    }

    let point_len = points.len();
    for start_i in 0..point_len {
        for finish_i in start_i + 1..point_len {
            let start_p = points[start_i];
            let finish_p = points[finish_i];

            let center = (finish_p + start_p) / 2.;
            let mut transform = Transform::from_translation(center);
            if center.x == 0.0 {
                transform = transform.looking_at(finish_p, Dir3::Y);
            } else if center.y == 0.0 {
                transform = transform.looking_at(finish_p, Dir3::Z);
            } else if center.z == 0.0 {
                transform = transform.looking_at(finish_p, Dir3::X);
            } else {
                transform = transform.looking_at(finish_p, Dir3::Y);
            }

            if transform.forward() == Dir3::Z
                || transform.forward() == Dir3::X
                || transform.forward() == Dir3::Y
                || transform.forward() == Dir3::NEG_Z
                || transform.forward() == Dir3::NEG_X
                || transform.forward() == Dir3::NEG_Y
            {
                println!(
                    "center: {:?}\t start: {:?}\t finish: {:?}",
                    center, start_p, finish_p
                );
            }

            commands.spawn((
                PbrBundle {
                    mesh: meshes.add(Cylinder::new(0.02, start_p.distance(finish_p))),
                    material: materials.add(StandardMaterial::default()),
                    transform,
                    ..default()
                },
                Object,
            ));
        }
    }
}


If someone could help me either debug this or orient me in an idiomatic way to do this I would be grateful.

i've toyed with this issue and managed to a partial fix. Basically the geometry of the cylinder object make it so that the height of the cylinder is perpendicular to the direction the cylinder looks at. hence instead of using a cylinder, I used a cuboid with his length being on the y axis so that the direction the segment looks at is the same as the length of the object.
